# Join on the same two tables more than once using different foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, inner-join

I am looking to retrieve the names of two different clients from a table called **Clients** as 'c' using Primary Key *ClientID*.

**[Sales Details]** as 'sd' contains *clientID*, firstName, lastName, saleDate, saleAmount, *recipientID*. Both sd.clientID and sd.recipientID are foreign Keys to c.ClientID.

Here is the query I am working with so far:

```
SELECT  
        sd.saleId                        AS 'Sale_ID'
       ,sd.clientId                      AS 'Client_ID'
       ,NULL
       ,c1.firstName + ' ' + c1.lastName AS 'Purchased_by'
       ,sd.description                   AS 'Purchased_pricing_option'
       ,sd.paymentAmount                 AS 'For_amount'
       ,CASE
           WHEN sd.recipientID IS NULL THEN 'SELF'
           ELSE sd.recipientID
        END                              AS 'RecID'
       ,c2.firstName + ' ' + c2.lastName AS 'Purchased_for'
       ,sd.createdDateTimeUTC            AS 'Purchased_on'
       ,NULL
       ,sd.grossUnitPrice                AS 'Total_paid'
FROM    [Sales Details] sd
        INNER JOIN Clients c1
            ON sd.clientID = c1.clientID
        INNER JOIN Clients c2
            ON sd.recipientId = c2.clientID
WHERE   sd.SaleID = 'SALEIDHERE'
```

In short, I need to see Purchaser Name along with the Recipient Name. Am I thinking along the right track?

After testing, this seems to work perfectly fine. Could there be performance issues with this type of setup? Not sure I understand your suggestion, Loser.

```
        INNER JOIN Clients c1
            ON sd.clientID = c1.clientID
        INNER JOIN Clients c2
            ON sd.recipientId = c2.clientID
```

Comment: The second `JOIN` should be `LEFT JOIN` since `recipientId` is nullable. That way *for self* sales will included in the result.

Comment: What problems are you having?  Your query looks like it should run to me.

Comment: Good catch, Felix. Thank you. I don't have access to my work Database at the moment. While I was writing this earlier I could not figure out the best way to generate this data and this information isn't covered in LearningSQL or SQL Cookbook (not that I could find at least).

Comment: Looks like you're on the right track to me.

Comment: If you want to join the same clientID, you dont need to use two join. Or one of the`c.clientId` is `c2.clientID`

Comment: scratch that ---- works perfect. Loser, is there some performance issues that I should be avoiding here?